# Bind function-field of the matlab struct with other struct's fields

Tags: matlab, function, binding, handler

Suppose there is a simplest `matlab struct` with several variables and function handler. I need to bind this function handler to other structure's field, so that the handler is able to change these variables.

Something like this:

```
function newStruct = createStruct()

   newStruct.input  = unifrnd(-1, 1, [9 9]);
   newStruct.kernel = unifrnd(-1, 1, [7 7]);
   newStruct.output = zeros(3, 3); 

   function f() 
      newStruct.output = conv2(newStruct.input, newStruct.kernel, 'valid'); 
   end    

    newStruct.fnc = @f;   
end

strct = createStruct();
strct.fnc();
```

It's not working, but is this possible to implement?

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: @CST-Link, R2013a 64-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to do is try to work in an object-oriented way with Matlab. The most recent versions of Matlab accept special syntax to declare classes. For example, your code would be rewritten (the code needs to be in a file that has the same name as the class, i.e. `MyClass.m`):

```
classdef MyClass < handle

    properties
        input;
        kernel;
        output;
    end;

    methods
        function obj = MyClass()
            input  = unifrnd(-1, 1, [9 9]);
            kernel = unifrnd(-1, 1, [7 7]);
            output = zeros(3, 3);
        end

        function f(obj) 
            obj.output = conv2(obj.input, obj.kernel, 'valid'); 
        end  
    end;
end;
```

Then you can instantiate and modify your object like:

```
my_obj = MyClass();
my_obj.f();
disp my_obj.output;
```

More details here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html

Answer (score 1):

Same as [@CST-Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24362553/684399) with automatic update of `Output`, using `Dependent` keyword:

```
classdef MyClass < handle

    properties        
        Input = unifrnd(-1, 1, [9 9]);
        Kernel = unifrnd(-1, 1, [7 7]);
    end

    properties (Dependent)        
        Output;         
    end
    methods         
        function [output] = get.Output(this)
            output = conv2(this.Input, this.Kernel, 'valid');
        end
    end

end
```

Which can be used like this:

```
obj = MyClass();
obj.Output; % No need to call `f` before to get `Output` value
```